# Class cast exception in WSO2 custom mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I was implementing custom mediator . I need to change payload inside my mediator class . I was using using following code

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
    

        
        System.out.println("inside the mediate  class pRequest ");
        
        try {
            org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = 
                      (org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext) context;
                
            //JsonUtil.newJsonPayload(axis2MessageContext,success, true, true); 
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

While executing i get class cast exception as follows  ,

**org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext**
Executing custom mediator.....RESTUploadDocument
at com.uia.document.RESTUploadDocument.mediate(RESTUploadDocument.java:43)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:94)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:440)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:135)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:113)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:325)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.r
Is there anything wrong in the code ,  what would be the right way to change payload  inside the  custom mediator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MC 
          = ((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext();
```